# Z-axis Calibration Fault in Prusa i3 MK3S

Tags: print-quality, print-failure

When I give the print command from Pronterface this how it's printing. The Z value is 10.00, can't solve the issue even after first layer calibration being carried out.

[image: print after 1st layer calibration.]

Comment: More details are required for a sensible answer.

Comment: The material is PLA. I have clearly put forward the necessary details if you are in want of further details, please specify the information you need.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/396/4762) to see what minimal details are required. Also, please [edit] and add any additional info to the question and not in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: `... solve the issue event after...` - Should that be *... solve the issue **even** after*...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your question, it seems that the Prusa i3 mk3 (which I also have) is set up for z=0 to be the proper height.

I do not use pronterface, so I don't know what special failures it may be causing.  If the Prusa is calibrated for z=0 to be at bed level, and the printer is printing at z=10, and shows z=10 on the UI, then it is likely that it is being programmed for z=10.  The question is, why?

Because the printer is calibrated, and is reporting that Z=10 at the point of failure, I do not suspect a mechanical problem with the printer.

I have sliced objects that were not properly touching the bed, which has caused this kind of offset.  Perhaps you could check that the object appears to be flat on the bed before you slice.  I had one case where a very thin spike stuck out of the mesh and lifted the object up (in the virtual slicer space) so that only the spike touched the bed, and since the spike was so small, it generated no extrusions.

There may also be calibration functions of pronterface to allow for adjustment to printers that are not properly calibrated.  Since I don't use pronterface, I don't know it, but I would suggest reviewing all the deep and hidden menues for something to tweek.